# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm

How do I create a task view to see what tasks are overdue by user - how do I get this emailed  directly to my boss to look at

Is it possible to set up a task view for leads that have not been contacted or reminders not attended to ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How basic do you want the answer to be? Do you know how to customise an entity and create a new view? 
Emailing a View is not simple and the alternative of using a report is frankly not worth it. If a manager won't look at a dashboard a few times a day, you have a much bigger adoption problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about setting up a view for leads that have not been contacted or reminders that have not been attended to, Dynamics CRM does not have the functionality to do this out of the box. However, Cobalt has an excellent plugin called Intelligent Query that will search for records that do not have an associated record.

http://blog.cobalt.net/blog/building-not-in-queries-using-dynamics-crm-advanced-find

If for some reason that option doesn't work for you, there are a couple of workarounds.

- For leads/contacts/accounts you can create a marketing list with all records of that type and then remove the ones that *do* have an associated record. http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/10/01/how-to-find-ms-crm-records-without-activities-using-advanced-find/
- For other records the only other option would be to create a field on the record that indicates whether it has an associated record or not. So you could have a field on the account entity that gets ticked when an order is placed under that account, which would require a workflow.